# Gradle test task generating different results when run with Android Studio

Tags: kotlin, gradle, junit, reflection

I have a multi-module project. In the given example, I have an **SDK** module and an **APP** module. In **SDK** module I have declared an `MyApiException` class, which extends `Exception`. Then I have multiple classes which extends `MyApiException` and some of those have child as well. There are some `MyException` classes in APP module as well, which extend `MyApiException`. The SDK module is included in the `gradle.build`.

**The problem:**
I have a unit test which generates type hierarchy from the given task. This is happening by using reflection. These tests are located in the **APP** module.
I am running these tests with `MyApiException::class.java`, because I want to compare with expected type hierarchy.
When I run those tests in AS, they pass without a problem and print out the expected type hierarchy in the console.
When I run those tests with `./gradlew task test`, they fail and the type hierarchy printed out only contains classes from the **SDK** module. Is there some configuration I need to include in `build.gradle` so the tests take in count classes from different modules ? Some `testImplementation` I am missing?

Comment: Can you attach a link to your project?

Comment: No sorry I cannot. It's NDA.